# Differences between openpyxl.load_workbook() and pandas.read_excel()?

Tags: openpyxl

I recently had a project where I had to load in information from a large number of Excel files, each of which had 12 sheets I needed to read from. In previous projects like this, I was just using the following method:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = sheet1, engine = 'openpyxl')
# Grab what I need from this sheet

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = sheet2, engine = 'openpyxl')
# Grab what I need from this sheet
```

And so on. It ran fast enough with lower numbers of excel workbooks to read in. With this project, however, it took several hours. Then I tried doing it this way instead:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path,data_only=True,read_only=True)

ws = wb['sheet1']
# Grab what I need from this sheet
ws = wb['sheet2']
# Grab what I need from this sheet
```

And so on. This ran in about 20 minutes.

So if both methods were using openpyxl, why was the second one so much faster? Is it because I only opened the workbook itself once, rather than opening it each time I got a new sheet in the first method? If that's the case, how can I use the second method, but have the worksheets be read in as pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses openpyxl to read XLSX files. It then converts them into Dataframe objects but, because XLSX worksheets are row-based and Dataframes column-based that can use a lot of memory and thus time. You'll have to do this if you want do use Pandas but otherwise use openpyxl directly. For example, if you want to insert stuff into a database. For some tasks you can even use multiple processes. See the [notes on performance](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance.html) in the documentation.